# How to fix: "Cannot Find Module" when using dynamic require generated by babel-plugin-preval

Tags: webpack, babeljs, next.js

I'm trying to turn my file system into a navigation. I'm using [babel-plugin-preval](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-preval) to recursively walk the directory and get the files like so:

```
const getFilePaths = () => {
    const filepaths = preval`
        const fs = require('fs')
        const path = require('path')
        const getAllFiles = dir =>
        fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce((files, file) => {
            const name = path.join(dir, file);
            const isDirectory = fs.statSync(name).isDirectory();
            return isDirectory ? [...files, ...getAllFiles(name)] : [...files, name];
        }, [])
        module.exports = getAllFiles('./pages/learn')
    `
    return Promise.resolve(filepaths)
}
```

I'm then feeding those results into a function that tries to require a const meta = {} export from that file path.

```
export const buildLearnNode = filepath => {
    const node = buildIds(filepath)
    const fullFilePath = `../${filepath}`
    const {meta} = require(fullFilePath)
    return Object.assign({}, node, {
        title: meta.title || null
    })
}
```

If I hard code a file path in the require statement, it works. If I use the filepath variable returned from preval in any way, I get a failure like so:

Error: Cannot find module '../pages/learn/hvac/begin/how-to-fix-a-sink/step-1.mdx'

I found [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680) Github issue which suggests it may be a Webpack thing and it says to make sure it's restricted to a known path. I've manually added filepath prefix and even chopped the file extension off the files and manually added them, but nothing works. As soon as my result from preval touches the require it breaks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I think you have to reduce the potential dynamic path down to a certain size. I found that if I hard coded the entire string and worked my way backwards making each part of the filepath on the end increasingly dynamic it stopped working when the filepath was like hardcoded 3-4 deep. 

More info on this here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-451034292

so 'a/path/to/a/thing/${filename} worked, and I did 'a/path/to/a/${pathFragment} so on and at like 4 deep this error showed up. Dynamic path can't be too large.